# Large header image on top of the sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

I wanted to make the image as sharepoint first header. Image should be set as background and the sharepoint name should be on top of it. There should be no quick links and the content should be displayed in the center.

Is it possible, quick response is much appreciated.

I have attached the example image.[image]

In the above example - I need the header background as given here, and as you see there is no quick link or any ribbon menu option. I need the same as in image

Comment: How can you tag with Sharepoint online AND Sharepoint foundation AND SharePoint Enterprise? You can hardly be using all three. The answer will depend on what you are actually using, so please tag ONLY the version you are working with. And it's not about a SharePoint Add-in ,either, so please remove that tag. You are sending people in totally wrong directions with your tags. Don't tag with anything you can find. Select the tags CAREFULLY to reflect YOUR environment.

Comment: Yes you are right, I didn't get the solution on the question. So am just reframing. and also @Teylyn - am very new to xharepoint and really not sure about the group. don't know whether the topic am talking abt is related to SP add in or not. if its not relevant to your area, then please ignore.